# AWS CloudFormation: cannot delete stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I use Github Workflow to deploy my Lambda NET6 to AWS.
One of steps in my yml file is to delete stack

aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name ${{env.LAMBDA_STACK_NAME}} --force

This command works fine in terminal but in Wokflow I receive an error:

Unknown options: --force

How to fix it? How to delete non-empty stack ?

Comment: The `aws cloudformation delete-stack` doesn't have a `--force` option.  https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/delete-stack.html. (I assume you are using the cli v2). You must be able to just run the delete command and the stack should be deleted. There are some cases where Cloudformation may fail to delete it, for example if the stack has termination protection enabled.

Comment: I have a failed Github Workflow, so try to delete stack before. But still unclear: Waiting for changeset to be created..
Waiting for stack create/update to complete

Failed to create/update the stack. Run the following command
to fetch the list of events leading up to the failure
aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name pmx-stack
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.

Comment: What is the stack status? Also, what are the errors in the Events tab?

Comment: Stack is in rollback_failed. When I deleted it manually and run workflow again the function deployed ok. But I'd like do not intervent manually

Comment: I'm afraid there is no an automatic solution for that. When the stack is in that state you must resolve the issue manually.